# Proof for $\{p,p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)\}\vdash (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$ in HR

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I can't find a for $\{p,p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)\}\vdash (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$ in HR

HR is the following system:

**axioms:**

$A\rightarrow A$

$(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow ((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$

$(A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow (B\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))$

$(A\rightarrow (A\rightarrow B))\rightarrow (A\rightarrow B)$

and the inference rule is MP.

I already proved that general claim that might help:

If $T,A\vdash B$ and $T\nvdash B$ than $T\vdash A\rightarrow B$

So here it's easy to prove that $\{p,p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r),(p\rightarrow q)\}\vdash r$ ,

but I have know idea how to show that  $\{p,p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)\}\nvdash r$

Comment: Do you have *Deduction Theorem*, i.e. : "if $T,A \vdash B$, then $T \vdash A \rightarrow B$" ? If so, from you "intermediate result" : $\{ p, p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r),(p \rightarrow q) \} \vdash r$, you must apply it (with $p \rightarrow q$ as $A$) to get : $\{ p, p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \} \vdash (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$.

Comment: Are you sure that in your "general claim" you need $T \nvdash B$ ?

Comment: I mean that, if the assumption $T \nvdash B$ is not needed, what you have proved **is** the *DT*; so you can apply it as suggested in my first comment ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA These axioms are **not** sufficient to deduce the deduction theorem. it looks like a limited relevant logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that we do not have the resource of *Deduction Theorem* available.

(1) --- $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ --- Assumption

(2) --- $p$ --- Assumption

(3) --- $(q \rightarrow r)$ --- from (1) and (2) by *modus ponens*

(4) --- $\vdash (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow ((q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r))$ --- Axiom 2

(5) --- $\vdash (q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow ((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r))$ --- from (4) and Axiom 3 by *modus ponens*

(6) --- $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ --- from (3) and (5) by *modus ponens*

Now we need the following form of Axiom 4 [$(A→(B→C))→(B→(A→C))$ - we use the substitution : $p \rightarrow q/A; p/B; r/C$ ] :

> (7) --- $\vdash ((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow ((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r))$

(8) --- $p \rightarrow ((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r)$ --- from (6) and (7) by *modus ponens*

Now, it's done : apply *modus ponens* using the Assumption $p$, and we will get :

> > $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$.

The conclusion "depends" on the assumptions : $p$ and $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$.

Comment: I am not sure if your method is correct, I think your previous attempt was much better (athough i think it has small mistakes) , first you have to prove that $ p \to ((p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q)\to r)) $ or 
$ (p \to (q \to r)) \to (p \to ((p \to q)\to r)) $ is a theorem of HR and only after that you have proved that $ { p, p \to (q \to r)} \vdash (p \to q) \to  r $ is valid. (this because $ p \to (q \to p) $ is not a theorem of HR and I am not sure about $ (p \to q )\to ( p \to (p \to q ))$

Comment: @Willemien - I think that you are misreading the statement of the problem (and my proof also) : we are not trying to prove $\vdash (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$, and in my proof the last formula has **not** the symbol "$\vdash$" upfront. We are deriving $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$ from the set of assumptions : $\{ p, p→(q→r) \}$. In my proof I use them and I do **not** discharge them (I'm using an *Hilbert-style* system, and not *Natural Deduction*).

Comment: The problem is a bit that you use a mix of (real) axiomatic logic but start by using the assumptions directly at the start. I am of the opinion that you may only use the assumptions at the very end  (so only **after** you have proven that  $ p \to ((p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to r)) $ is a theorem) maybe this is just my personal preference. Hilbert is not any longer around to tell us what his style really was. But my idea is that you should prove theorems first and entailments / deductions later.

Comment: @Willemien I don't see anything invalid with Mauro's proof here.  That said, proving theorems first I do think a generally more powerful way to go about things.  For example, if you have {(p→q), (q→r)} $\vdash$ (p→r), that is less powerful than having [(p→q)→((q→r)→(p→r))] since [(p→q)→((q→r)→(p→r))] entails {(p→q), (q→r)} $\vdash$ (p→r) with just detachment and it also implies a rule like (p→q) $\vdash$ [(q→r)→(p→r)], while {(p→q), (q→r)} $\vdash$ (p→r) doesn't entail [(p→q)→((q→r)→(p→r))] (unless you have a suitable deduction theorem), nor the rule (p→q) $\vdash$ [(q→r)→(p→r)].

Comment: @DougSpoonwood the problem is that Mauro **assumes** the deduction theorem , and it is just that my problem is about, it is no good assuming anything. BTW thanks for your proof

Comment: @Willemien - **NO**, it's not so ! The standard def of *derivation* of $A$ from $\Gamma$ [see Mendelson, page 34] : $\Gamma \vdash A$ is : "a sequence $B_1, ... B_k$ such that $A=B_k$ and, for each $i$, either $B_i$ is an axiom or $B_i$ is in $\Gamma$ or $B_i$ a direct consequence by some rule of inference of some of the preceding formulae in the sequence." The above proof is **not** a proof of $\vdash (p→q)→r$ by the *DT*, but a derivation of $(p→q)→r$ from $\Gamma = \{ p, p→(q→r) \}$. I can understand that you do not "like it" ... but it is correct. :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA does Mendelson describes logics where the deduction theorem fails? Often the deduction theorem is just assumed, I have read it fails in logics where $ (P \to ( Q \to R)) \to ((P \to Q) \to (P \to R)) $ is not a theorem (Gottwald's " A Treatise on Many Valued Logics"(2001) page 133 result 6.81 ). But I am wondering if these are the only logics where the deduction theorem fails. Gottwald does assumes that $ P \to ( Q \to P) $ is a theorem.

Comment: @Willemien Mauro didn't assume the deduction theorem here.  The deduction theorem can fail with [(P→(Q→R))→((P→Q)→(P→R))] holding, but [P→(Q→P)] failing.  For example, a fragment of some relevant logic http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/C-pure-R-page.htm has [(P→(Q→R))→((P→Q)→(P→R))] as a theorem, but [P→(Q→P)] fails (I found a proof of  [(P→(Q→R))→((P→Q)→(P→R))] using Prover9 from Ulrich's 4 axioms, and a model which satisfies those 4 axioms, but not [P→(Q→P)] using Mace4).  The deduction theorem with detachment is equivalent to {[(P→(Q→R))→((P→Q)→(P→R))], [P→(Q→P)]} under detachment.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Maybe you are right and I am a bit to strict here, but I think by using premisses (formula's that are not theorems) before you have proved the theorem, is in my (very strict) vieuwpoint allready using the deduction theorem. But i guess i am a very strict here.

Answer (score 0):

Since Willemien thought it better to show that [p→((p→(q→r))→((p→q)→r))] is a theorem, I'll do that here.

I use [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Your axioms are:

3 Cpp (weak law of identity)

4 CCpqCCqrCpr (syll or hypothetical syllogism)

5 CCpCqrCqCpr (commutation or "transposition")

6 CCpCpqCpq (contraction or Hilbert)

I use the notation Dx.y * z for [condensed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensed_detachment) [detachment](http://www.clas.ufl.edu/users/jzeman/modallogic/chapter01.htm#Detachment,%20substitution,%20and%20application) with x as the major premise, y as the minor premise, and "z" as the resulting formula. I'll also write the annotation of the proof before the proof.

D4.4 * 8

```
 8 CCCCqrCprsCCpqs
```

D5.4 * 9

```
 9 CCqrCCpqCpr
```

D5.3 * 10

```
 10 CpCCpqq
```

D4.10 * 11

```
 11 CCCCpqqrCpr
```

D9.6 * 12

```
 12 CCrCpCpqCrCpq
```

D11.4 * 13

```
 13 CpCCqrCCpqr
```

D5.13 * 14

```
 14 CCpqCrCCrpq
```

D8.12 * 15

```
 15 CCpqCCqCprCpr
```

D5.15 * 16

```
 16 CCqCprCCpqCpr
```

D16.14 * 17

```
 17 CCrCpqCrCCrpq
```

D5.17 * 18

```
 18 CpCCpCqrCCpqr
```

Now we assume {p, CpCqr}.  By 18 and "p" we detach CCpCqrCCpqr.  From CpCqr and CCpCqrCCpqr we detach CCpqr.