# Proof of $p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r)\vdash_{HR} (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

Let HR be an Hilbert style proof system:

Inference rule: MP

Axiom schemes:

1. $A\rightarrow A$
2. $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow ((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))$
3. $(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow(B\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))$
4. $(A\rightarrow(A\rightarrow B))\rightarrow B$

Prove formally that $p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r)\vdash_{HR} (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$

I've seen this similar question:

[Proof for $\{p,p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)\}\vdash (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$ in HR](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714433/proof-for-p-p-rightarrow-q-rightarrow-r-vdash-p-rightarrow-q-rightarrow)

However, they use $p$ as an additional assumption, and I don't know how to prove it without that assumption

Comment: Note that your axiom 4 is different from the fourth axiom in the question you link to.

Comment: You're right, maybe that's the reason for the diffrence, but it seems like they didn't use that axiom in the proof

Comment: x @user11: You certainly can't prove what you want with the first three axioms only, because _they_ (and MP) make a sound system (wrt classical semantics) when taken alone.

Comment: Only axioms 2 and 4 are needed to prove this.  A condensed detachment proof goes D2.2 = 5.  D5.4 = 6.  D6.6 = ((x→y)→x) or 7.  D7.7 = (x→y) or 8.  D8.8 = x or 9.  Thus, by substitution in 9, (((p→q)→r)→((p→q)→r)) is a theorem (and every other well-formed formula follows also).  The rule of inference then follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow ((q\rightarrow r)\rightarrow(p\rightarrow r))$ - Axiom 2
2. $(q\rightarrow r)\rightarrow ((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(p\rightarrow r))$ - (1) and axiom 3, MP
3. $p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r)$ - Assumption
4. $p\rightarrow ((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(p\rightarrow r))$ - (3), (2) and axiom 2, 2 MPs
5. $((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow (p\rightarrow r))\rightarrow(p\rightarrow ((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r))$ - Axiom 3
6. $p\rightarrow (p\rightarrow ((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r))$ - (4), (5) and axiom 2, 2 MPs
7. $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$ - (6) and axiom 4, MP

Answer (score 2):

What you want to prove does not hold.

If $p$, $q$ and $r$ are all **false**, then $p\to(q\to r)$ is true, but $(p\to q)\to r$ is false.

Comment: We don't claim HR has the soundness property

Comment: @user11: Huh -- then it is misleading in the extreme to call it a "proof system for propositional logic".

Comment: OK, I deleted that

Comment: @HenningMakholm One could claim that such is a valid proof system for one-valued propositional logic.  In other words, a propositional calculus with just one truth value.  Like all one-valued logical propositional calculi, any arbitrary variable is a theorem of this system.  If that's the semantics, this system is sound with respect to such semantics.